# Retrieve dictionary item by number

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, key

I have a `Dictionary` where the key and value are both strings. It's possible to get the value of a key by using `[]`. But the `[]` expects a string. Is it possible to get the value of a key by using a number instead of the String key?

```
Dictionary<String, String> m_GermanEnglish = new Dictionary<String, String>();
m_GermanEnglish.Add("der", "the");
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?  it feels like you must be doing something wrong if you have an index you want to turn into a value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use LINQ

```
m_GermanEnglish.ElementAt(index);
```

But you are relying on implementation that you don't know or is guaranteed.  Dictionary does not guarantee the elements to be in a certain order.

Comment: +1 Whilst this will likely work forever, there is nothing stopping the implementation from being changed in the future and causing your code which uses this to break in horrible ways.  You have been warned.

Answer (score 6):

the `IDictionary` interface makes no guarantees about order of the items when enumerating the dictionary, the dictionary is inherently unordered.  Therefore, there is no such thing as 'the item at position 1' as the collection is unordered.

It would be valid for the items to appear in a different order each time you enumerate the dictionary.

If you need to also access the items by index then you need a different data structure, like an `IOrderedDictionary` implementation.  there is one [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO) which basically keeps a list side by side with the dictionary to provide access by index.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot index into dictionaries by ordinal as items don't have an ordinal in the obvious sense, it only exposes the key as an index. Dictionaries also do not guarantee order. Add a key or remove a key, and it is ***indeterminate*** where that key will land in terms of "memory position".

If you want to get stuff out by an ordinal index, then I'd guess you need a different collection and not the `Dictionary<>`.

Perhaps a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`? Obviously this doesn't give any duplicate support, but it lets you pair items and gives you an index.

Comment: Semantically, correct. However, it's going to be easy enough to simply enumerate the dictionary in a foreach to expose it as a set of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` elements.

Comment: @Tejs Indeed, but that involves knowing the "why" behind needing to index the items out.

Comment: @Tejs True, but there is no guarantee that the items will be in the same order as entered, so indexing to them would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 2):

The order of items in a dictionary is undefined: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx  That is, the order of the values collection is only guaranteed to be in the same order as keys, but Dictionary reserves the right to change them.

Other options:
You could look at the old NameObjectCollection -- it does what you are asking, but it predates generics, so it's just a dictionary of object (and if you use reflector to view the NameObjectCollection, you will see that they did the same thing -- they really implement 2 collections, a HashTable and a List).

You could store them only in a list, and search using LINQ, but wether this is a good solution depends upon how many items you need to store (dictionary lookup is O(1), List searching is going to be O(n) at best.

Answer (score 1):

Using the extension functions in the System.Linq namespace, you can do the following:

```
var indexedDictionary = m_GermanEnglish.ToArray();
var pairAt0 = indexedDictionary[0];
```

You could also use the `.ToList` extenstion function instead of `.ToArray`.  They both return a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects.

**Note:** The entries in a Dictionary may not necessarily be sorted in the same order as the order they were put in.

If you need to maintain a certain ordering to your Key/Value pairs in your dictionary, you're better off using either a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) or a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319).  In my testing, SortedList tended to be ~2x faster on lookups and indexing by key, but SortedDictionary was ~100 times faster on removing entries.

Comment: This is suboptimal because you have no idea how the resulting array will be arranged, and to arrange it would require an extra (relatively slow) call.

Comment: I was just remembering that as well and made sure it was included in the answer.